# How to get thigs out from list of dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have some problems with getting things out from list of dictionaries.

1. I want to find student with best average from all school subjects and function needs to return students id with best average
2. Function that will find best average from math and return student id with best average
3. function that will calculate grades of all students

I finished third task, but right now i'm a little bit stuck with 1,2 points. I don't know how am I suppose to get out students id with average and print it.

Help/tips much apreappreciated.
PS: I don't want to use "list comprehension" only loops.
Code below

```
students = [
    {
        "id":1,
        "math":[1,4,3,4,2],
        "english":[2,2,4,3,2,1,1],
        "history":[4,1,2,5,5]
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "math":[1,1,5,4,2],
        "english":[5,5,3,4,2,1,5,5],
        "history":[3,3,3,4,5,1]
    },
    {
        "id":3,
        "math":[1,2,1,3,4,3],
        "english":[1,3,3,2,3,3,3],
        "history":[3,3,3,4,5,1]
    },
    {
        "id":4,
        "math":[3,3,3,2,1],
        "english":[4,4,3,3,4,5,5],
        "history":[1,2,2,3,4,4]
    },
]

def average(value):
    return round(sum(value) / len(value), 2)

def all_students_average(student):
    class_scores = []
    for student in students:
        for k, v in student.items():
            if k in ["math", "english", "history"]:
                for score in v:
                    class_scores.append(score)
    average_grades = average(class_scores)
    print(average_grades)

def math_students_average(student):
    math_scores = []
    for student in students:
        for k, v in student.items():
            if k in ["math"]:
                for score in v:
                    math_scores.append(score)
    average_math = average(math_scores)
    maximum = max(math_scores)
    print(maximum)





math_students_average(students)
all_students_average(students)
```

Comment: create a nw dictionary, loop over all studdent-dicts. use the student-id as key and store the average score as value. loop over the whole new dict and find the highest key,value pair from the items ... just one way to do it - what exactly is your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this(sorry for the alignment cant align it properly at stack overflow) for you first function(best overall average student) and second function (best maths average):-(Let me know if there is any issue)

```
def funct1andfunt2(students):# students is your list of dictionaries
bestmathsaverage=[0,0]#at 1st element is index of student and 2nd element is the average
bestoverallaverage=[0,0]#at 1st element is index of student and 2nd element is the average
for i in range(len(students)):
    studentsmathaverage=sum(students[i]["math"])/len(students[i]["math"])
    if bestmathsaverage[1]<studentsmathaverage:
        bestmathsaverage[0],bestmathsaverage[1]=i,studentsmathaverage
    studentsoverallaverage=sum(students[i]["english"])/len(students[i]["english"])
    studentsoverallaverage+=sum(students[i]["history"])/len(students[i]["history"])
    studentsoverallaverage+=studentsmathaverage
    if bestoverallaverage[1]<studentsoverallaverage:
        bestoverallaverage[0],bestoverallaverage[1]=i,studentsoverallaverage
return bestmathsaverage,bestoverallaverage
```